Is there a string metric for the dictionary distance between two words?
If I use Microsoft Excel to sort the strings
Abba
Abbaa
Abbaz

it will sort them in the order above - ignoring the case, as I want it to do.
However, a measurement like Levenshtein distance would give the same score for Abba <> Abbaz and Abba <> Abbaa. Systems like metaphone exist to quantify the pronunciation difference between strings, but that is not what I want to do. Metaphone or soundex would tell me that Abba is closer to Abbae than it is to Abbab - for me, the reverse should be true.
Since this about comparing personal names, different combinations up to about 100 characters should be considered. This is work and I don't have a choice about what software I use - it has to be Excel & I can't use VBA.
Below is my dead-end attempt to come up with a workable solution - since it definitely won't work feel free to skip reading it, but I wanted to show I tried.

I decided to get fancy, and give each letter a prime number, so that A in the first position is represented by the number 2, B in the first position is represented by 3, etc.
In this system, A in the second position would be represented by the 27th prime, which is 103. B in the second position would be 107, and so on.
Using this system, the string Abba would be represented by

Multiplying those primes together would give the number 21539314.
To obtain no remainders, this number can only be divided by the numbers 2, 107, 251 and 401. These are the primes attached to the letters a,b,b,a in their respective positions in the system I described.
This was as far as I got - as yet unresolved was how to work out how many possible products of primes are between e.g. abba <> 21539314 and abbaz <>15788317162.
As I didn't know, but you can probably guess, I never got to the point of working it out, because before I could I encountered the tragedy of floating point error - in Excel numbers longer than 15 digits are not accurately recorded. Any name longer than 6 letters, and a lot of names before that threshold, will not get their 'proper' number.
My understanding is that this is a limitation of 64-bit memory addresses, so even if I could use other software, this would not help. It also occurs that, since this approach uses gigantic numbers for tiny text strings, it is probably fundamentally wrong even if there was no floating point issue.

Edit:
Yes, any string of letters a-z is a valid word, in this case.

If it's work, you should be able to tell your boss that the technology provided to you is incapable of doing it, but another technology could. They should then let you use the appropriate technology, or tell the customer that it's not possible given the constraints, if the constraint comes from them.

If there's a technology which can do this, I'd be very interested to hear the solution and it will no doubt be helpful for many people. However this comment, while of course right in an ideal world, only applies to people who have some power to get their employers to do things. I work for an organisation which is very conservative and ponderous - and I don't think I'm the only one here who can't just install whatever software I feel like. Unlike most of the people who post answers, but like many of the people who post questions, I am stuck with Office, Powershell, batch and whatever else comes with Windows.

It sounds like you want to create a totally new type of string distance metric, rather than use an existing one (like one of the ones you mentioned above), is that correct?

I was hoping that something similar to what I described already existed. If it doesn't, then yes I want to create it and I showed my failed attempt at doing that.

Are you trying to create an total-order from a distance? That doesn’t work in general.

I'm trying to determine a distance, and tried to create a total-order so that I could create a distance from that (as I mentioned, I couldn't create the total order).

What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? Do you need to serialize a string as a number or just compare 2 strings for sorting? Or are you trying to calculate a number that represents how far away 2 words are from eachother?
I assume you only want to support characters from A to Z for your use case?

I am trying to calculate a number that represents how far away 2 a-z words are from each other. Serialising a string as a number was my attempt at doing that. I don't just need to know what word in a given list it would be next to, but to put  a number on how close it would be in the dictionary.

It's an interesting problem, here when you say "dictionary" we assume any string of characters is a valid word, right?
My first thought would be to reverse the string and treat it as a base 26 number (a=0, b=1, c=2, etc...), not sure if that's possible in excel.

If it's work, you should be able to tell your boss that the technology provided to you is incapable of doing it, but another technology could. They should then let you use the appropriate technology, or tell the customer that it's not possible given the constraints, if the constraint comes from them.

It sounds like you want to create a totally new type of string distance metric, rather than use an existing one (like one of the ones you mentioned above), is that correct?

Are you trying to create an total-order from a distance? That doesn’t work in general.

Thanks for the interest all, replied to comments in question.

I'm not sure exactly how it's done in Excel, but if you already applied your solution it shouldn't be too hard to modify.
First, instead of using prime numbers and multiplying which adds a lot of unused numbers, you should just take the number associated with the character directly and apply an exponent equal to it's position in the string such that:
abba = 1*27^0 + 2*27^1 + 2*27^2 + 1*27^3 = 1 + 54 + 1458 + 19683 = 21196

This method gives much more reasonable number than the product of primes.
(since we want the letter "A" at the end of words to have a weight this is actually base 27 with an unused 0) (This makes "AA" different from "A")
Edit: Don't forget to invert the string or use the length minus the position as the exponent
Edit 2: Just noticed this doesn't work like you want because "abc" would be smaller than "aaaa" because of length... You would need to pad your strings so they all have the same length, of course, the bigger the number of characters the larger your numbers will get. So instead of using the length to calculate the exponent you need to choose a number that you know you won't have any longer strings. The longest english word has 45 letters... 27^45 is ~2.58e64 Which is unfortunately larger than what you can represent in a signed 64bit integer.

Thanks, this is an interesting idea. Actually "aaaa" should be smaller than "abc" because it would come first in the dictionary. When I get back to work on Monday I'll see about applying your solution. Thanks.
